# Vectors poorly displayed on Chrome for Android canvas

Tags: android, google-chrome, html5-canvas, antialiasing

I've done a bit of searching around, but haven't really found anything that might help me solve this problem. I recently switched my canvas images to vectors, which has worked great on everything but Chrome for Android (tested on 30+). Specifically in this example of using EaselJS for all of my canvas stuff.

UPDATE:
http://jsfiddle.net/mcfarljw/hnMLU/ Check out this fiddle on your mobile with Chrome to see the problem.

Is there anything I can do to have it smooth things out?

[image: vectors drawn on a android chrome canvas]

```
//check fiddle for live code
var stage = new createjs.Stage("demo");
var stroke = new createjs.Shape();
stage.addChild(stroke);
stage.update();
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you did wrong without seeing any code. Please try to create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/examples/GraphicsTest.html If you load this example on Chrome for Android it'll produce the same kind of outcome as my image. If you load it in Firefox for Android it'll look nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure its discussed over here:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=285066

They've disabled anti aliasing in Chrome Android but decided a few hours ago to revert the change. So all you can do is wait for the Fix...

Comment: Where are you seeing that they've decided to revert it?

Comment: It's a little late, but I've gone ahead and accepted the answer. The latest build of Chrome Beta has included the fix and from my tests it works.

Comment: http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2013/11/chrome-beta-for-android-update_20.html